# Open outlook email when user clicks on a button - Classical ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I do a have a submit button which will gives a confirmation messagebox when clicked. If user clicks on YES then it needs to open an outlook email on client side. Can you please provide me the sample code for that ?

Something like this ...

```
<a href="mailto:someone@website.com">Email</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: So basically you want to activate a `mailto` link (maybe a hidden one) when a button is pressed? Is Outlook itself related to the question or is that just what `mailto` links open for you?

Comment: There is no link like <a>. I have only a button. When clicked on the button, i want to open outlook on client side. - Thanks

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have Outlook? What if they're using some other mail client? Is it okay if that opens instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a place to start. You'll need to wire your "Yes" button to submit the form. The "Yes" button here is to demonstrate that a button can launch a `mailto` action.

```
<html>
  <body>

   <form action="mailto:somebody@wherever.foo">
      <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
   </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

personally, I don't think this is possible with classic asp.

However most browsers will automatically select the default email program, visitors are able to set or change their default email program for browsers, for example:

Mozilla Firefox:
1. Click on 'Tools'
2. Choose 'Options'
3. Click on the tab 'Applications'
4. Scroll down to 'mailto' and select the Action for to your program.

Offcourse these settings are per browser different and need to be set by the visitor.

I know this is not the solution you are looking for, but at least it's explained.